# Product information not coming in Adaptive Search Hybris 1808

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have enabled Adaptive search for my project on Hybris 1808_7. I am getting solr facets and search profile information but still, product information is not getting rendered in the editor area.
Can anyone let me know what I am missing? Please find attached screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Backoffice is build with [widgets](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1808/en-US/633a1253bf3844eea4ac13f681c198da.html). I suggest you to read the documentation that I've provided and read about ZK Framework too because that is how widget UI is created (it's almost like a HTML but it's a little bit different. [Here](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference) you can find more about this framework). And to answer to your question, your problem comes from a widget because the product information is rendered dynamically like in this file: `searchResultBrowser.zul`, and to be more specific, for example here:

`<html sclass="yas-result-title" conntent="@load(vm.sanitizeHtml(result.document.fields['name']))">`

You will have to look after `result` item and see how it's retrieved and then see if **your** product is retrieved the same.